# Determine which child view is in front in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, view

I have several child views loaded onto a parent view. Certain functions send the current view to the back of the stack, using .sendtoback. How can I determine if a view is is currently in front of the other views? Checking the "visible" property does not work because all views are technically set to visible; it's just that all but one of the views are hidden by the other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Control.ControlCollection.GetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the index of child controls.

According to the description on MSDN:

> The control with an index value of zero is at the top of the z-order, and higher numbers are closer to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

See the below link from a C# version of this question.

[How to check if a userControl is in front of others in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299283/how-to-check-if-a-usercontrol-is-in-front-of-others-in-c)

The code in VB.net should look like this.

```
Private Function IsControlAtFront(control As Control) As Boolean
    Return control.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(control) = 0
End Function
```